# wget ERROR 400: Bad Request

Tags: shell-script, wget

I have a list of URLs to be downloaded through wget. For a single file when I enter following command in shell it downloads and saves file correctly.

```
wget -O IPSL-CM5A-LR-tasmin-Historical-19500101-19501231.nc https://dataserver.nccs.nasa.gov/thredds/ncss/bypass/NEX-GDDP/bcsd/historical/r1i1p1/tasmin/IPSL-CM5A-LR.ncml?var=tasmin&north=55&west=72&east=136&south=16&horizStride=1&time_start=1950-01-01T12%3A00%3A00Z&time_end=1950-12-31T12%3A00%3A00Z&timeStride=1
```

However when I put use it in the following script for a list of URLs I get following error.

```
while read -r line; do wget -O $line; done < one_model.txt
```

> Connecting to dataserver.nccs.nasa.gov
>   (dataserver.nccs.nasa.gov)|169.154.146.41|:443... connected.
>   **HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request 2020-01-07 10:30:47 ERROR 400: Bad Request.**

Comment: You need to provide some more details. Can you pass the `--debug` flag to Wget so we can see exactly what the server replied back with?

Answer (score 1):

The line in your script should work in a somewhat untidy way.  Check that there are two fields in your file of URLs, first the output file and then the URL with a space separating the two.